# Select ListView Item by checking checkbox C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, listviewitem

I have UserControl with ListView, the ListView have TileView and the items contain Checkbox, Icon and label.

I found a way to check the checkbox with clicking on the Icon, but I want to select the item by checking the checkbox.

Comment: I have ListView (ListView1), every row have Checkbox(checkB), Icon(icon), label(lblname).  I  want to select the row by clicking on the checkbox

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you means. 
But the ListView has a property ListItemIndex (or something like it).

This is an int, 
-1 no row selected
0 to Count-1 from collection to select the row.

So you can bind this property to a property in your view model to select a specific row per programing.

Comment: I need to select the listview item by clicking on checkbox

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. You want to select a specific ListView row. Or you mean something else?

Comment: Yes. By clicking on the checkbox.